# In a completely closed system with no access to Air, will stirring (from a motor) decrease cooling time?

Tags: thermodynamics, fluid-dynamics

Given:

A closed, square bottle of water with a Thermo-electric Cooler cooling the water inside a bottle by chilling a piece of metal that touches the water.

No leaks, no access to air, all cooling comes from the Thermoelectric cooler.

Question:

Would adding a motor that spins the water slightly inside the bottle (still no access to air) allow the water to chill faster if the only source of cold is the Thermo Electric cooler?

I have read a lot about atmospheric pressure being reduced by stirring, allowing better heat absorption, less inside bottle insulation from temperature differences, but have been wondering if this is true for a specific case.

Thank you

Comment: Can you cite some references about atmospheric pressure being reduced by stirring and how that mechanistically results in more rapid heat transfer?

Answer (score 0):

I would have thought that energy is being added to the system. Heat is the excitation of molecules. You are exciting the molecules more by stirring.